# Paypal Get Subscription Details

Tags: paypal

My website is using subscriptions payments and the old programmer did not used ipn, to activate the account he used a custom return url (ya, very stupid).

The issue here, is that old subscription does not have any custom information attached to the ipn (new subscriptions are ok).

Is there a way to find out the return url used in the initial payment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to view this information from the PayPal account.  However, the account holder can contact PayPal and have them check the transaction details of one of these old transactions, and they can tell him what the redirect/return URL was for that transaction.  If you have any trouble getting this information from customer support, the account hold can also open up a ticket with PayPal MTS at www.paypal.com/mts requesting the information.  He would need to use the email address registered on his PayPal account and he would need to provide a transaction id for one of the transactions that the client wants the return URL for.  If you have any trouble after that just let me know, send me a PM with the ticket number.

Comment: It is possible to change the invoice number of every old subscription? So any new payment can be recognized using the invoice number?